# "sockets disabled, connection limit reached" with lighttpd

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I've been having a lot of those in my lighttpd's log files for the last few weeks:

```
2011-09-18 19:30:17: (server.c.1405) [note] sockets disabled, connection limit reached 
2011-09-18 19:31:15: (server.c.1359) [note] sockets enabled again 
2011-09-18 19:31:15: (server.c.1405) [note] sockets disabled, connection limit reached 
2011-09-18 19:32:18: (server.c.1359) [note] sockets enabled again 
2011-09-18 19:32:18: (server.c.1405) [note] sockets disabled, connection limit reached 
2011-09-18 19:33:21: (server.c.1359) [note] sockets enabled again 
2011-09-18 19:33:21: (server.c.1405) [note] sockets disabled, connection limit reached
```

Even if I have in my configuration file:
    server.max-fds = 0

I don't have any idea what I can do with those errors, it's killing my website.
Any expert around here?

Answer (score 3):

```
server.max-fds = 0
```

This only works if `lighttpd` is started as root.

are you running `lighttpd` as root ?

Answer (score 2):

`server.max-connections = NUMBER`

If you use PHP, set `server.max-fds` to the double of `server.max-connections`.